# Using System.String.Split from F#

Tags: f#, f#-3.0

I would like to use the .NET CLR version of String.Split in F#. Specifically I would like to use this code:

```
let main argv = 
    let s = "Now is the time for FOO good men to come to the aide of their country"
    let sepAry = [|"FOO"; "BAR"|]
    let z1 = s.Split sepAry
    0 // return an integer exit code
```

This fails to compile however, due to the fact (I believe) that the version of Split in F# is implemented differently than the one in .Net 4.5.
The version from .NET that I would like is:

Split(String[], StringSplitOptions)     Returns a string array that contains the substrings in this string that are delimited by elements of a specified string array. A parameter specifies whether to return empty array elements.

I understand that I am getting the F# version of Split, which formerly resided in the PowerPack and that is why the implementation differs from the CLR version.

What is the best way to get what I want? Is it possible to override the F# version of Split and use the .Net version? Is it possible to extend the F# version and if so, how?

Comment: AFAIK, the PowerPack never included any special (i.e., F#-specific) implementations of String.Split.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The overload you want to use expects a second argument.

```
let z1 = s.Split (sepAry, System.StringSplitOptions.None)
```

It's not an “F# version of `Split`”, it's exactly that `Split` you see in C#.

Answer (score 0):

2 things are the problem here:

1. For .NET BCL you need to specify (), because the parameters are declared in different way using tuples (See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd483468.aspx)
2. Only the char[] overload exists without StringSplitOptions. If you want to use a string array, you also need to specify StringSplitOptions.

You could create your own F# overload method, that provides a default for the stringsplitoptions.

Answer (score 0):

Kirelagin is right, the Split method on String your trying to use doesn't exist, it's only available for char arrays with no secondary argument. You have to resort to this version: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf.aspx. Also you have to use parentheses around your arguments when calling none-f# .NET apis because the arguments in C# are defined as a tuple.

You could of cause define your own extension-method on String, this way you don't have to specify None all the time if that is your expected default behavior

```
type System.String with
  member x.Split(separator : (string [])) = x.Split(separator, System.StringSplitOptions.None)
```

Comment: Minor correction - you do not actually have to use parentheses when calling .NET methods that take a single argument (but I would recommend that, but that is really just a matter of style). You do need them for methods taking multiple arguments (a tuple).

Comment: Your right Tomas, the tuple thing can get a bit harry since they are in fact only syntactical tuples (that's what the spec says: http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/spec.html#_Toc335819028). I believe this section "If there are no named actual arguments, and M has only one candidate method, which accepts only one required argument, ignore the decomposition of arg to tuple form. Instead,arg itself is the only named actual argument." is what specifies that you don't need parentheses when the method only takes one argument and it's given in unnamed form.